# s3sync automate amazon backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

I am really new to shell script etc.

i am trying to get s3sync to work i have installed ruby with the rubyinstaller i am on windows and have been using the cmd prompt that you get after installing ruby.

Can someone help me with these error??

```
C:\Sites\s3sync>s3cmd.rb listbuckets
C:/Sites/s3sync/HTTPStreaming.rb:53:in `<module:S3sync>': uninitialized constant
 S3sync::SimpleDelegator (NameError)
        from C:/Sites/s3sync/HTTPStreaming.rb:52:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/s3sync/s3try.rb:28:in `<module:S3sync>'
        from C:/Sites/s3sync/s3try.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/s3sync/s3cmd.rb:16:in `<module:S3sync>'
        from C:/Sites/s3sync/s3cmd.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

I have been following this article but now i am stuck

http://blog.eberly.org/2006/10/09/how-automate-your-backup-to-amazon-s3-using-s3sync/

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

While I have not done a S3sync setup in windows, I have successfully written a CentOS / Plesk setup.

This error looks very familliar, and it looks like your config files are not set up properly.  I'd check the file you store the AWS credentials in, and then also check the config file carefully. Make sure there are no leading slashes ('/')  and trailing slashes only if required.  Spaces... anything can set this script off with an error.

Good luck, let me know how you go.